# Can I use a case statement instead of an if statement in this code?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, case

As you can see there are a lot of `if` statements in the code below.

Can I replace them with a case statement?

```
package CBM;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Board 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    int minplayers, maxplayers;
    minplayers = 2;
    maxplayers = 8;
    String player_0, player_1;

    System.out.println("Start game? (Y/N)");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String yn = sc.next();
    if (yn.equals("Y"))
        System.out.println("Starting");
        else
        {
            if (yn.equals("N"))
                System.out.println("Ending");
        }
    System.out.println("How many people are playing?");
    int players = sc.nextInt();
    if (players >= minplayers && players <= maxplayers)
        System.out.println("There are " + players + " players");
        else
        {
            if (players < minplayers || players > maxplayers)
                System.out.println("2-8 players only.");
                System.out.println("Ending");
        }

    if (players == 2)
        System.out.println("To begin both players must each roll the dice once"
                + " to decide who goes first.");

    else

    if (players == 3)
        System.out.println("To begin all 3 players must each roll the dice once"
                + " to decide who goes first.");
    else

    if (players == 4)
        System.out.println("To begin all 4 players must each roll the dice once"
                + " to decide who goes first.");
    else

    if (players == 5)
        System.out.println("To begin all 5 players must each roll the dice once"
                + " to decide who goes first.");
    else

    if (players == 6)
        System.out.println("To begin all 6 players must each roll the dice once"
                + " to decide who goes first.");
    else

    if (players == 7)
        System.out.println("To begin all 7 players must each roll the dice once"
                + " to decide who goes first.");
    else

    if (players == 8)
        System.out.println("To begin all 8 players must each roll the dice once"
                + " to decide who goes first.");
```

Comment: yep, `switch (players) {case 2: ....; break ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `if` *or* `switch`. Just insert the player count dynamically (with an exception for the first case):

```
if (players == 2)
    System.out.println("To begin both players must each roll the dice once"
            + " to decide who goes first.");
else
    System.out.println("To begin all " + players + " players must each roll the dice once"
            + " to decide who goes first.");
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to check for `players == 2` since you want to print out the word **both**, in all other cases you can just print out the variable `players`since you have already checked it is in the correct range `(2-8)` earlier in your code.

```
if (players == 2)
    System.out.println("To begin both players must each roll the dice once to decide who goes first.");
else
    System.out.println("To begin all " + players + " players must each roll the dice once to decide who goes first.");
```

If you want to use a switch statement you do this:

```
switch (players) {
  case 2:
    System.out.println("To begin both players must each roll the dice once to decide who goes first.");
    break;
  default:
    System.out.println("To begin all " + players + " players must each roll the dice once to decide who goes first.");
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your Reply :)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to check when `players == 2` and when `players > 2` to delete many unnecessary cases.
Anyway, if you want to use case statement it will be:

```
switch(players)
{
 case 2:
 //your code
 break;
 case 3:
 //your code
 break;
 ...
 }
```